# cloud-based epub reading system with offline reading AND collections -- what are my options?

Tags: epub, google-play-books, android, collections, cloud-based

Google Play books is getting to be cumbersome on so many levels. Most importantly, the android app has no way to organize ebooks by collections or different shelves.

Yet Google Play Books is really the only cloud-based epub reader I know of -- and its epub support is  good.

I end up preferring to import files to the Kindle android app because  Kindle's collections are so easy to create and edit. Am I overlooking any other options?

In other words, are there any cloud-based epub reading systems which allow offline reading, importing your own epubs  and the ability to create collections? Having a store connected to it would be ideal, but I buy DRM-free epubs generally or get things from Project Gutenberg.

I am looking for a software solution (i.e., an app) rather than a device solution I realize that Kobo or ibook devices might have a cloud component, but I would prefer not to be locked into one hardware family. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Aldiko book reader is a really good app that has the most of the features you require.

Comment: Thanks. The upcoming version sounds good but their website's emptiness does not inspire confidence. Also, I noticed that FBPremium has a cloud-based solution (though possibly it does not work offline; I will test -- they are coming with a new version in January. https://books.fbreader.org/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

BookFusion is what you are looking for. BookFusion provides you with a cloud based platform and native Android and iOS apps to allow you to easily upload , organize and read your eBooks across all devices.

More at https://www.bookfusion.com/reading/cloud-library

It is device agnostic and as a result you can read and access your books on any device. You are also able to select the books that you would like to be made available offline from your library in our iOS and Android apps.

Disclosure: I am the founder of BookFusion. Please feel free to take it for a spin and let us know if you have any additional feedback

Answer (score 1):

I use neat reader to sync and read epub books.

https://www.neat-reader.com

It has Android,win, Mac and web version and the iOS version would coming soon. You could import your books and read it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you can read Chinese, you might be interested in 微信读书 http://weread.qq.com

Answer (score 1):

If you really need web reader to be part of solution (Google Play Books have web reader) - bookfusion is very likely answer you looking for. Web/Android/iOS.
Disadvantages: subscription (but earlier you lock in in early access one - better price you get). Library Interface/library management on mobile apps could be better. Vendor lock in (there is no official way to access your own account if you want to do some scripting,etc except via their opensource calibre plugin. if this plugin or web interface is enough for you - good.). Support is usually much better than next alternative.

If Android-only solution is ok and you have pc/mac - you could look at Calibre+Calibre Companion + Moon+ Reader/Librera. Disadvantages: It looks like Calibre Companion will be subscription-based soon. You need to store whole synced library on device. You need to solve position issue yourself (webdav solves this for Moon+). Moon++CC doesn't play good with each other on Android 11 (Librera plays but position sync doesn't work even while it should work). PDF (and not only epub) - works better. Fully opensource solution.